# Converting this parametric curve to a level curve

Tags: parametric, plane-curves

I want to convert the parametrized curve $\gamma(t) = (\cos^{3}(t), \sin^{3}(t)), \ t \in \mathbb{R}$ to a level curve.

Let $C = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^{2}}: x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = 1\}$.  I claim that $x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = 1$ describes the same points in the plane as $\gamma$.

If we let $x = \cos^{3}(t)$ and $y = \sin^{3}(t)$, then $x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = 1$ is satisfied so the image of $\gamma \subset C$.  However, I'm having trouble showing the reverse inclusion (ie. $C \subset$ image of $\gamma$).  I've seen in many places where they claim these two sets to be equal but I don't see how to show it.

Comment: If $(x,y) \in C$ then $(\sqrt[3]{x}, \sqrt[3]{y})$ lies on the unit circle, so there is some $t$ such that...

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense - I missed that.  Thanks